# Anonymous collection initializer for a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, anonymous-types, collection-initializer

Is it possible to implicitly declare next `Dictionary<HyperLink, Anonymous>`:

```
{ urlA, new { Text = "TextA", Url = "UrlA" } },
{ urlB, new { Text = "TextB", Url = "UrlB" } }
```

so I could use it this way:

```
foreach (var k in dic)
{
   k.Key.Text = k.Value.Text;
   k.Key.NavigateUrl = k.Value.Url;
}
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A dictionary where value is an anonymous type in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```
var dict = new[] {
            new { Text = "TextA", Url = "UrlA" },
            new { Text = "TextB", Url = "UrlB" }
        }.ToDictionary(x => x.Url);
// or to add separately:
dict.Add("UrlC", new { Text = "TextC", Url = "UrlC" });
```

However, you could just `foreach` on a list/array...

```
var arr = new[] {
    new { Text = "TextA", Url = "UrlA" },
    new { Text = "TextB", Url = "UrlB" }
};
foreach (var item in arr) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Text, item.Url);
}
```

You only need a dictionary if you need O(1) lookup via the (unique) key.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only with great workaround, and only within a method.

This is how you can do it:

```
    static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> NewDictionary<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        return new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }
    public void DictRun()
    {

        var myDict = NewDictionary(new { url="a"},
            new { Text = "dollar", Url ="urlA"});
        myDict.Add(new { url = "b" }, new { Text = "pound", Url = "urlB" });
        myDict.Add(new { url = "c" }, new { Text = "rm", Url = "urlc" });
        foreach (var k in myDict)
        {
            var url= k.Key.url;
            var txt= k.Value.Text;

            Console.WriteLine(url);
            Console.WriteLine(txt);    
        }

    }
```

You can refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c) for more info.