# Shortcuts for overly terse generic types

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to pass a parameter of Dictionary to a method.

```
public static void Method(Dictionary<string, string> hash)
```

I'd really like to use the inline collection initializer

this is not legal

```
Method({{"Foo", "Bar"}, {"Bing", "Bong"}})
```

neither is this

```
Method(new {{"Foo", "Bar"}, {"Bing", "Bong"}})
```

this is

```
// outside the class    
using D = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;
// calling with the type alias
Method(new D {{"Foo", "Bar"}, {"Bing", "Bong"}})
```

so is this

```
// once in a library somewhere
class SD : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> {}
// calling with the class
Method(new SD {{"Foo", "Bar"}, {"Bing", "Bong"}})
```

do you have a good shortcut like this I'm not aware of for solving my type collection initialization?

Comment: I'd rather be clear than terse (or worse, having using statements that work as short-hand), what is the problem with typing it out?

Comment: @ronBeyer No problem typing it out. Just asking if it `can` be done, not it it `should`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815252/anonymous-collection-initializer-for-a-dictionary is another way, but its almost as long-hand as `new Dictionary<string, string> { ... }`.

Comment: dont need an anonymous as the value...

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't declare a dictionary the way you're wanting.  In C#6, there is a slightly prettier `Dictionary` initializer syntax, but it's not exactly what you want:

```
using D = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>;

//...

Method(new D { ["Foo"] = "Bar", ["Bing"] = "Bong" });
```

Comment: horray for alternatives to the dynamic duo Foo+Bar

Comment: @JJS my coworker is preferable to `["Shirt"] = "Pants"`

Comment: this made me go looking for other metasyntactic variable names. There is even a foo RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3092...