# Dictionary(string -> tuple) in .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net-3.5, dictionary, anonymous-types

I was wondering if there's a way to create a dictionary using an anonymous type for its values.
Something like

```
{
    { "first",  {1, true} },
    { "second", {2, false} },
}
```

I want to use this in .NET 3.5, so there's no vanilla implementation of Tuple<...> available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c

Answer (score 0):

What I generally use (though this is ugly and assumptive) is:

```
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Object())
dict.Add("first", New Object() {1, true})
dict.Add("second", New Object() {2, false})
```

Obviously, this doesn't provide the compiler support for type- and bounds-checking your tuples, but in a pinch it works.