# How to retrieve a dictionary with anonymous value from the Cache in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, dictionary

I created a dictionary from a Linq query result as suggested from stackoverflow questions answer: [A dictionary where value is an anonymous type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp)

```
var intToAnon = sourceSequence.ToDictionary(
e => e.Id,
e => new { e.Column, e.Localized });
```

I have added this new object into my ASP.NET cache. How can I read it from the cache (`HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add`)? I imagine I need reflection but not sure how to go about it.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve an anonymous type you'll either need to use reflection or [cast-by-example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/713602/55847), neither of which are a good idea in this case.

Instead, either create your own custom type to hold the data, or use one of the built-in [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) types:

```
// dict will be a Dictionary<TId, Tuple<TColumn, TLocalized>>
// where TId, TColumn and TLocalized are the actual types of those properties
var dict = sourceSequence.ToDictionary(e => e.Id,
                                       e => Tuple.Create(e.Column, e.Localized));
Cache["yourCacheKey"] = dict;
```

Then when you get the object from the cache just cast to the appropriate `Tuple` type:

```
// i'm assuming here that Id is Int32, Column is String, and Localized is Boolean
var dict = (Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, bool>>)Cache["yourCacheKey"];
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, could you show how one could use Tuple instead of the dictionary projection? I first attempted this with no success (lack of understanding)

Comment: Great, this looks like what i need.... Thousands thanks. I Did not want to create a custom type for this and i think your suggestion does exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I 'm having one more issue with this question. My sequence returned need to be grouped before being added to the dictionary. When doing so, i can not add it to the dictionary way show suggested above. How can i do this? I'm currently receiving an exception "An item with the same key has already been added."