# Passing arguments like in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In mvc, you can pass arguments like so

```
  new { A = B, C= "D", E ="F", ... }
```

I'd like to pass arguments like so to my own procedures, looking for links to any samples/tutorial for the same

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes for this question. The author is clearly an inexperienced C# programmer, but the question is valid and makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using ASP.NET MVC then you'll need to use reflection in your method as stated in an answer above, but if you're writing an ASP.NET MVC extension method you can use
HtmlHelper method called `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` which creates `RouteValueDictionary` from anonymous object or use RouteValueDictionary constructor that takes anonymous object to initialize its values.

Comment: Great, pointed me to the right direction from the answer by jpbochi here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp since that answer is from 2010 was hoping to find something better using expando perhaps

Answer (score 2):

It is object initialization check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) MSDN article

Answer (score 1):

You should look into anonymous types and reflection in C#.

In short:

1. Your method will accept an object
2. You use reflection to see get at the properties of the passed object.