# Initializing a dictionary with anonymous objects

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization, anonymous-types

I'm trying to do the following.

```
private static Dictionary<int, object> MAPS = new Dictionary<int, object>
{
  {1, new {1, 2, 3}}
};
```

It doesn't work as I'd expect based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx), so I'm pretty certain that the issue is that I'm using anonymous objects. Supposed that I don't want to create a new type for my thingies and still want to keep all the mappings in the same dictionary, what should I do?

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619518/a-dictionary-where-value-is-an-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp) but it's a bit dated now so I'm hoping there's something new for that in the framework.

Comment: Instead of saying _"doesn't work as I'd expect"_ it would be helpful if you'd show the actual compiler error, which is _"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster Point taken. I assumed that it was something basic and that I just got a brain poof. But you're correct, no argument.   :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this if you want an array of `int`s as the value.

```
private static Dictionary<int, object> MAPS = new Dictionary<int, object>
{
  {1, new[] {1, 2, 3}}
};
```

Or this if you want an anonymous class

```
private static Dictionary<int, object> MAPS = new Dictionary<int, object>
{
  {1, new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}}
};
```

Or better yet don't use `object`.  Use `int[]` or `List<int>` for a collection of `int` or declare a class or struct if you need specific values.  Maybe even use `Tuple<int,int,int>` if you just need 3 `int`s for each value.  But, in general you should try to avoid the need to cast to and from `object`.

Comment: Oh, I tried setting brackets on **both** the new operator **and** the object type in the angles. And I tried colon instead of equality sign. Stupid JSON damaged me...   :)   +1

Comment: Is it possible to type the *a*. *b* and *c* without declaring a class for them?

Comment: They will implicitly take the type of what you set them to, so if needed you can cast the value.  But the main problem you'll have with an anonymous class here is that you can not cast to it when you pull the value from the dictionary.  You might want to look into using `dynamic` instead of `object`.

Answer (score 3):

Further to the answers from @TimSchmelter and @juharr, if you want to be able to reference the properties via their names but you don't want to create a class you could use `dynamic` (although obviously you won't get any intellisense so it's use is limited):

```
Dictionary<int, object> MAPS = new Dictionary<int, object>
{
    {1, new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3} as dynamic}
};

Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)MAPS[1]).b); //prints 2
```

Or if you made the `Dictionary` a `Dictionary<int, dynamic>` you could forgo the cast which makes life a little easier:

```
Dictionary<int, dynamic> MAPS = new Dictionary<int, object>
{
    {1, new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}}
};

Console.WriteLine(MAPS[1].b); //prints 2
```

The only benefit to using `object` or `dynamic` is that you can have a collection with different types stored in it. If you are only storing `int`s then you're best off using a `List<int>` or `int[]`.

Answer (score 2):

An anonymous type is just a type with **properties**, your anonymus type has no properties:

```
private static Dictionary<int, object> MAPS = new Dictionary<int, object>
{
    {1, new { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = 2, Prop3 = 3}}
};
```

But how do you want to cast from object to that anoymous type?

**Edit**: *Good question there, though. Do I have to cast MAPS[1][0] or is there a way to force a type implicitly there?*

You cannot cast an object to an anonymous type without a hack like this extension method:

```
public static T CastByPrototype<T>(this object obj, T prototype)
{
    return (T)obj;
}
```

It uses a prototype anonymous type like:

```
var prototype = new { Prop1 = 0, Prop2 = 0, Prop3 = 0 };
```

Now this works:

```
var value = MAPS[1].CastByPrototype(prototype);  // you can use value.Prop1
```

It fails with an `InvalidCastException` if the prototype has not identical properties(in the same order).

Comment: Good question there, though. Do I have to cast *MAPS[1][0]* or is there a way to force a type implicitly there?

Comment: @KonradViltersten if you want to be able to get to a value with `MAPS[1][0]` then why not make it a `Dictionary<int, int[]>` or `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` instead?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `new {1, 2, 3}` is [not a collection initializer nor an anonymous object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). What type of object do you want to create?

Use something like `new { elements = new[] { 1, 2, 3 } }` to give the anonymous object an `elements` property containing the integers.

Or you can name the individual properties: `new { foo = 1,  bar = 2, baz = 3 }`.

Comment: I want to have a dictionary that for a given integer gives me two different integers.