# How can I return a Dictionary<int, object>?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, iqueryable, anonymous-types

This works:

```
public IDictionary<int, object> GetProducts( int departmentID )
{
    return new Dictionary<int, object>
                {
                    { 1, new { Description = "Something" } },
                    { 2, new { Description = "Whatever" } },
                };
}
```

But for some reason this doesn't:

```
public IDictionary<int, object> GetProducts( int departmentID )
{
    var products = ProductRepository.FindAll( p => p.Department.Id == departmentID );

    return products.ToDictionary( p => p.Id, p => new { Description = p.Description } );
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
public IDictionary<int, object> GetProducts( int departmentID )
{
    var products = ProductRepository.FindAll( p => p.Department.Id == departmentID );

    return products.ToDictionary( p => p.Id, p => new { p.Description } );
}
```

The compiler error (in both cases) is:

```
Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,{Description:string}>' to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<int,object>'
```

I assumed it was a problem with the ToDictionary Linq extension method, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1619530/1015595) it should work since FindAll returns an `IQueryable<Product>`:

> ... if your data is coming from an IEnumerable or IQueryable source, you can
>   get one using the LINQ ToDictionary operator and projecting out the
>   required key and (anonymously typed) value from the sequence elements:
>
> ```
> var intToAnon = sourceSequence.ToDictionary(
>     e => e.Id,
>     e => new { e.Column, e.Localized });
> ```

What gives?

Comment: Be aware that you'll have to cast the value to something other than object to do anything useful with it.  Since the actual value is an anonymous type, you'll need to resort to reflection or `dynamic`, neither of which are compile-time safe.  You would be better off creating a concrete class and using _that_ as the resulting value type.

Comment: Well, the return value is serialized as JSON, which is quite useful. Creating a model just for the purpose of serializing JSON seems redundant to me.

Comment: True - that is a valid usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about explictly casting the dictionary value to `object`?

```
return products.ToDictionary( p => p.Id, p => (object)new { Description = p.Description } )
```

Actually, an anonymous object is an instance of a compile-time randomly-created regular class, thus it's an object but it's of some particular type. This is why you **can't** expect an implicit cast to `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Maybe if `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` would support [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) `TValue`...

Comment: Can you clarify your covariant comment? I'm not sure how that would solve the problem.

Comment: @DStanley This is why I said "if it would had...", I've not entered to the discussion about if it's possible or not...

Comment: @DStanley I've rephrased the last sentence :D

Answer (score 6):

It's a bad practice working with anonymous types like you did. Don't try and wrap them as an `object`. If you need anonymous types, use them at the same method context you're defining them.

What about just changing your method:

```
public IDictionary<int, object> GetProducts( int departmentID )
{
    return new Dictionary<int, object>
                {
                    { 1, "Something"},
                    { 2, "Whatever"},
                };
}
```

And then cast the object back into a string?

Of course that's assuming you can't just change the type to `IDictionary<int, string>`

Comment: The value actually needs several properties (not just description) such as price, name, color, etc. I only included one property in my example to make it simple. Why is it bad practice?

Comment: @Koveras because you cannot cast the object back to the anonymous type.  You'll be forced to use `dynamic` or reflection to get at the properties.  It's usually better to create classes to put your values in.

Comment: @Koveras In your case it also sounds legitimate to create an additional Product class to save the data