# List of anonymous types?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types

I need to create pairs / triples of *something* and store it somewhere. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var item=new { a=i , b="lala" ,c=4.5m}; //anonymous type
}
```

But then I thought: `List<what>`?

I could use dynamic but I want Intellisense.

*(I could have also use `Tuple<int,string,decimal>` but if I already have what I need (`=new { a=i , b="lala" ,c=4.5m};`), why should I use other type (tuple)? )*

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Does "something" derive from an interface or a class?

Comment: no. I create it on the fly. ( like in my sample)

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a list of the anonymous type?

Comment: Well, you've discovered the drawback of anonymous types: **they have no name** (that can be used in a statically-typed context). Only *implicit* type inference will work with them (or widening out to Object/dynamic, of course). This why newer .NET versions add the Tuple class(es) - the Tuple types *have* a name and can *pass across* boundaries where type inference cannot.

Comment: @pst what makes you think I dont know that ?  :-) my conflict showes exactly the problem

Comment: This is basically what `Tuple<>` has been designed for.

Comment: Won't you have intellisense for the var?

Comment: @flup That was in relation to `List<object> theList = ..` I believe, as `var theList = ..` would be intellisense'd correctly.

Comment: Anyway, FWIW, see https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx (it's ugly, but ..)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use type inference

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0,100)
                      .Select(i => new { a=i , b="lala", c=4.5m })
                      .ToList(); // not necessary (you can use IEnumerable)
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir sorry, didn't get what you mean by *captured var issue*. If you want to use items several times, then it's better to use `ToList()` or `ToArray()`. If you going to iterate once over items, then just use `IEnumerable<T>` of anonymous type (further enumerations will create new items). That's why I've added that comment on `ToList()`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, how you fill fields within `for`, but could you try:

```
var lstOfSmth = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                            .Select(i => new { a = i, b = "lala", c = 4.5m })
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

> why should I use other type (tuple)

Because they have been designed exactly for this purpose. If you're afraid of verbose code, the `using` directive comes to the rescue, too.

```
using myPair = Tuple<int,string>;
using myTriple = Tuple<int,string,decimal>;
//...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myPair pair = new myPair(1,"string");
    myTriple triple = new myTriple(i,"lala", 4.5);
}
```

Comment: Alex - the 4.5m is not a unit of measure (it's not meters). It's forcing the 4.5 to be a decimal instead of a floating point number, which is a world of difference numerically speaking.

Comment: Oh shame I missed it. I'll fix things up