# SelectMany Anonymous Type and Skip Iterations

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, linq

I've been trying for a long time to find a "clean" pattern to handle a `.SelectMany` with anonymous types when you don't always want to return a result.  My most common use case looks like this:

1. We have a list of customers that I want to do reporting on.
2. Each customer's data resides in a separate database, so I do a parallel `.SelectMany`
3. In each lambda expression, I gather results for the customer toward the final report.
4. If a particular customer should be skipped, I need to return a empty list.
5. I whip these up often for quick reporting, so I'd prefer an anonymous type.

For example, the logic may looks something like this:

```
//c is a customer
var context = GetContextForCustomer(c);
// look up some data, myData using the context connection
if (someCondition)
  return myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 });
else
  return null;
```

This could be implemented as a foreach statement:

```
var results = new List<WhatType?>();
foreach (var c in customers) {
  var context = GetContextForCustomer(c);
  if (someCondition)
    results.AddRange(myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 }));
}
```

Or it could be implemented with a `.SelectMany` that is pre-filtered with a `.Where`:

```
customers
  .Where(c => someCondition)
  .AsParallel()
  .SelectMany(c => {
     var context = GetContextForCustomer(c);
     return myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 });
  })
  .ToList();
```

There are problems with both of these approaches.  The `foreach` solution requires initializing a `List` to store the results, and you have to define the type.  The `.SelectMany` with `.Where` is often impractical because the logic for `someCondition` is fairly complex and depends on some data lookups.  So my ideal solution would look something like this:

```
customers
  .AsParallel()
  .SelectMany(c => {
     var context = GetContextForCustomer(c);
     if (someCondition)
       return myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 });
     else
       continue?   return null?   return empty list?
  })
  .ToList();
```

What do I put in the `else` line to skip a return value?  None of the solutions I can come up with work or are ideal:

1. `continue` doesn't compile because it's not an active `foreach` loop
2. `return null` causes an `NRE`
3. `return` empty list requires me to initialize a list of anonymous type again.

Is there a way to accomplish the above that is clean, simple, and neat, and satisfies all my (picky) requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return an empty `Enumerable<dynamic>`.  Here's an example (though without your customers and `someCondition`, because I don't know what they are, but of the same general form of your example):

```
new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(i => {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            return Enumerable.Repeat(new { i, squared = i * i }, i);
        else
            return Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>();
        })
    .ToList();
```

So, with your objects and `someCondition`, it would look like

```
customers
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(c => {
        var context = GetContextForCustomer(c);
        if (someCondition)
            return myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 });
        else
            return Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>();
       })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This will cause a lot of dynamic calls, and in turn, reflection. Performance-wise, this is not the best option.

Comment: Good point.  But he also says he just needs this to generate some quick reports.

Comment: I like this solution the best, because it's short and doesn't require any custom extension methods.  I had tried `Enumerable.Empty()` but it couldn't determine the type, without `<dynamic>`.  Thanks!!

Comment: if you do this, realize the eventual return type will be `IEnumerable<dynamic>` as well. This might work fine depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `someCondition` and `myData` look like...

Why don't you just `Select` and `Where` the contexts as well:

```
customers
.Select(c => GetContextForCustomer(c))
.Where(ctx => someCondition)
.SelectMany(ctx => 
    myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 });
```

---

EDIT: I just realized you need to carry both the `customer` and `context` further, so you can do this:

```
customers
.Select(c => new { Customer = c, Context = GetContextForCustomer(c) })
.Where(x => someCondition(x.Context))
.SelectMany(x => 
    myData.Select(d => new { CustomerID = x.Customer, X1 = d.x1, X2 = d.x2 });
```

Comment: I realize my example doesn't do it justice.  In reality, the logic behind `someCondition` and `myData` is 20-30 lines of code and rapidly evolving, so I like it best all together in the `.SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
customers
  .AsParallel()
  .SelectMany(c => {
     var context = GetContextForCustomer(c);
     if (someCondition)
       return myData.Select(x => new { CustomerID = c, X1 = x.x1, X2 = x.x2 });
     else
       return Enumerable.Empty<int>().Select(x => new { CustomerID = 0, X1 = "defValue", X2 = "defValue" });
  })
  .ToList();
```

All anonymous types with the same set of properties (the same names and types) are combined into one one anonymous class by compiler. That's why both your `Select` and the one on `Enumerable.Empty` will return the same `T`.

Comment: This solution is basically in the same boat as the `foreach` and the `return` empty list - you have to dynamically construct a list of an anonymous type.  I am aware of solutions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689), for instance.  It works, but now I have two property lists I have to update if I decide to add/remove a property in my on-the-fly report.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own variarion of `SelectMany` LINQ method which supports `null`s:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> NullableSelectMany<TSource, TResult> (
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
    {
        if (source == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (selector == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
        foreach (TSource item in source) {
            IEnumerable<TResult> results = selector(item);
            if (results != null) {
                foreach (TResult result in results)
                    yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can return `null` in the `selector` lambda.

Comment: This is a nice approach.  The other thing I had considered was `.Select(...).Where(x => x != null).SelectMany(x => x)`.  Not as pretty, but doesn't require me to specify the anonymous type anywhere.

Comment: @mellamokb ReSharper suggested that to me actually. :) I also have many extension methods for `IEnumerable`, so I'd write something like `.Select(...).WhereNotNull().Flatten()` myself, which looks pretty enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer returns `dynamic`. The cleanest would be to move the filtering logic into a `Where` which makes the whole thing look better in linq context. Since you specifically rule that out in the question and I'm not a fan of delegates written over multiple lines in a linq call I will try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class), but one can argue its more hacky.

```
var results = new 
{ 
    customerID = default(int), //notice the casing of property names
    x1 = default(U), //whatever types they are
    x2 = default(V) 
}.GetEmptyListOfThisType();

foreach (var customerID in customers) {
  var context = GetContextForCustomer(customerID);
  if (someCondition)
    results.AddRange(myData.Select(x => new { customerID, x.x1, x.x2 }));
}

public static List<T> GetEmptyListOfThisType<T>(this T item)
{
    return new List<T>();
}
```

*Notice the appropriate use of property names which is in accordance with other variable names, hence you dont have to write the property names a second time in the `Select` call.*