# I am trying to convert my sort so that it can take any data type

Tags: c#

```
public class Sort
{
    // array of integers to hold values
        //made it object to support any data type
    private object[] array = null;

    // number of elements in array
    //made it object to support any data type
    private object x;

    public Sort()
    {
        //was an int
        array = new object[100];
        x = array.Length;
        Random rand = new Random(5433);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
        }
        PrintArray();
        q_sort(0, x - 1);
        PrintArray();
    }

    private void PrintArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i] + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(array[array.Length - 1]);
    }

    public void q_sort(object left, object right)
    {
        object pivot, l_hold, r_hold;

        l_hold = left;
        r_hold = right;
        pivot = array[Convert.ToInt32(left)];

        while (Convert.ToInt32(left) < Convert.ToInt32(right))//This will only take integers?
        {
            while ((array[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
            {
                right--;
            }

            if (left != right)
            {
                array[left] = array[right];
                left++;
            }

            while ((array[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
            {
                left++;
            }

            if (left != right)
            {
                array[right] = array[left];
                right--;
            }
        }

        array[left] = pivot;
        pivot = left;
        left = l_hold;
        right = r_hold;

        if (left < pivot)
        {
            q_sort(left, pivot - 1);
        }

        if (right > pivot)
        {
            q_sort(pivot + 1, right);
        }
    }
}
```

From what I have been able to find is that I need to do this with an object type. I am still new to C# so I am having a little bit of trouble with this. My code works if i only make it receive integers, doubles and so on. I am just not sure how to carry the type through the sort

Comment: 1st, you [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) over `arrays` and see [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Comment: You probably also need to ensure that `T : IComparable<T>` and use `Compare` instead of `<` and `>`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should update the title so that it says "sort", not "search".

Comment: It will also work for an array of strings that can be parsed to integers.  It will _not_ "work" for doubles, though, as doubles will get truncated to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should start by using a generic class like as follows:

```
public class Sort <T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private T[] array;
    private T object x;
    ...
    public void q_sort(T left, T right)
    {
        T pivot, l_hold, r_hold;
         ...
    }
}
```

Secondly, instead of using operators like `>=` `<=` `>` `<` or `=` to compare objects, use `obj.CompareTo(otherObj)` where obj and otherObj are type T.  You will then be able to figure out which order they are in based on the return value of `CompareTo`.  See

According to the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Less than zero    :
>   This object is less than the method parameter.
>
> Zero  :
>   This object is equal to the method parameter.
>
> Greater than zero     :
>   This object is greater than the method parameter.

Comment: Your syntax for the generic constraint is off, but otherwise it's a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked the syntax for generics and fixed it.