# Filter anonymous object list by executing string clause in where condition

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

[DOTNETFIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYcVoM)

I have create a anonymous object list like below.....

```
List < Object > _dynamicObjectList = new List < Object > ();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    _dynamicObjectList.Add(new {
        ID = i, Name = "stu" + i, Address = "address234324" + i, DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i)
    });
}
```

Now I need to create string query. My string query is given below..

`string searchStr ="it.ID= 1 ||  it.ID= 2 ||  it.Name= "stu1" ||  it.Name= "stu2"";`

In the last step I am going to filter my list with the above string...

`var returnList= _dynamicObjectList.GetFilteredData(searchStr );`

The method which executes Dynamic object is given below...

```
public static IQueryable GetFilteredData < T > (this IEnumerable < T > source, string searchCriteria) {

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria)) {
        IList < T > returnList = new List < T > ();
        returnList = source.AsQueryable().Where(searchCriteria).ToList();
        return returnList.AsQueryable();
    } else {
        return source.AsQueryable();
    }

}
```

During execution system provide an error

> No property or field 'ID' exists in type 'Object'

Answer (score 2):

`<T>` is `Object` because you're passing in a `List<Object>`, and an Object doesn't have the properties on it you're looking for.

If your `_dynamicObjectList` is declared as a list of those anonymous types then the query can be executed fine, for example if you declare `_dynamicObjectList` as:

```
var _dynamicObjectList = new[] {
            new {ID = 0, Name = "stu" + 0, Address = "address234324" + 0, DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0)},
            new {ID = 1, Name = "stu" + 1, Address = "address234324" + 1, DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)},
            new {ID = 2, Name = "stu" + 2, Address = "address234324" + 2, DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)},
            new {ID = 3, Name = "stu" + 3, Address = "address234324" + 3, DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)},
            new {ID = 4, Name = "stu" + 4, Address = "address234324" + 4, DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4)},
        }.ToList();
```

More info: [A generic list of anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

I think your best bet, if possible, would be to avoid using an anonymous type and just create a class to hold your data.

Comment: I need it for annonymus type list.

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure that the List you invoke that extension method on is always a List of the anonymous type objects, rather than a `List<Object>`. Are you expecting to put different kinds of anonymous objects in the list you're using?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to initialize your list is using Enumerable.Range and anonymous type:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i => new {
    ID = i, 
    Name = "stu" + i, 
    Address = "address234324" + i, 
    DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i)
});
```

Regardless of the way you initialize it, I see two major problems with your `GetFilteredData` method though:

1. You cannot  pass your anonymous type to a generic function. You would need to cast it to a `IEnumeration<object>` or use `dynamic` type, which totally defeats the purpose  of your anonymous type.
2. You need to parse text in `searchCriteria` to a some sort list of criteria, before it can be applied to your  collection. Depending on the allowed syntax, it could be a simple or not so simple task. When you get the parser, then you you'll need write an extension `.Where` method which accepts `string` as criteria.

You'll make your life easier if you define a regular type for your collection and clarify what the filtering criteria should be. Based on your example they could two simple lists - one for IDs, and another one  for Names. Then you can parse your string into those two collections and then use those collection to filter your original list.

Comment: The [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) library is being used. I'd never seen it before, but it provides the `Where` extension method which takes and parses the string.

Comment: Well, if the library does it for you, that's good. I've noticed that the NuGet package hasn't been updated since 2011, so check that it still works correctly with your setup (.NET version, etc.).