# PropertyInfo List is null when using reflection with generics

Tags: c#

I am using a method to try and iterate through an object to get all of the object's properties, some of which are lists of objects.

This all works except for the part where I check for objects within the initial object's properties. If it finds a list of objects I want it to iterate through them.

Annoyingly, I'm getting `null` on my list of whatever type.

I'm now getting an error in VS because `pt` isn't instantiated, but it would be at run time.

Below is the if statement I'm using to try and catch whatever object/List is being parsed.

Am I going the right (roundabout) way or doing this or is this completely wrong?

**Problematic Code - if statement null list:**

```
public static string DeconstructLists<T>(T obj, string body)
        {
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || property.PropertyType == typeof(int) || property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    body += property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(obj, null) + Environment.NewLine;

                else
                {
                    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        //null list exception
                        var list = (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(obj, null);
                        foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            DeconstructLists(item, body);
                        }

                        // stack overflow exception
                        //var props = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                        //foreach (var p in props.GetProperties())
                        //{
                        //    DeconstructLists(p, body);
                        //}
                    }
                }
            }
            return body;
        }
```

**Post create method:**

```
public ActionResult Create(Company cmp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.companys.Add(cmp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                // send email
                SendEmail(cmp);
                return RedirectToAction("Thankyou", "Home", new { form="ASN" });
            }
            return View(cmp);
        }
```

**Send email method:**

```
public static void SendEmail(Company cm)
        {
            string _body = "";
            string _subject = "ASN Form Request";

            _body = DeconstructLists<Company>(cm, _body);

            using (SmtpClient msgClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                msgClient.EnableSsl = false;
                msgClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                msgClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                msgClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
                    {                    
                        UserName = "",
                        Password = ""
                    };
                msgClient.Host = "";
                msgClient.Port = 0;

                using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage())
                {
                    msg.To.Add(""); // to add
                    msg.From = new MailAddress("");// from add
                    msg.Subject = _subject;
                    msg.Body = _body;
                    // preparing the message to be sent
                    msgClient.Send(msg);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Class objects:**

```
public class Company
    {
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string regNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Asn> asns { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        public int contactId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
    }
public class Asn
    {
        public int asnId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public bool userBehalf { get; set; }
        public bool something { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `(List<pt>)` ?! You cannot do that.

Comment: Yes I know but it was the best way to demonstrate what I'm trying to get, I want a list of whatever `property.PropertyType` is. Due to using generics I can't assign it as something and don't want an `if` or `switch` to check through the possible objects, I want to be able to parse anything to it and it'll iterate through the object's properties even if they're lists of objects. Apologies, hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Perhaps something like this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class

Comment: Thanks, shall take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If it finds a list of objects I want it to iterate through them.

You don't need a `list` for iteration, the minimum iteratable type is `IEnumerable`. In fact your `if` statement is checking just that

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
{
    // ...
}
```

So why not just using inside

```
var list = (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(obj, null);
foreach (var item in list)
{
    DeconstructLists(item, body);
}
```

**EDIT:** See this, it works, then see why yours does not:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tests
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var company = new Company
            {
                companyId = 1,
                name = "ACME",
            };
            company.asns = new List<Asn>
            {
                new Asn { asnId = 1, companyId = company.companyId, company = company  },
                new Asn { asnId = 2, companyId = company.companyId, company = company  },
            };
            company.contacts = new List<Contact>
            {
                new Contact { contactId = 1, companyId = company.companyId, company = company, name = "Contact1" },
                new Contact { contactId = 2, companyId = company.companyId, company = company, name = "Contact2" }
            };
            var body = DeconstructLists(company, "");
        }
        public static string DeconstructLists<T>(T obj, string body)
        {
            var type = obj.GetType();
            var properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || property.PropertyType == typeof(int) || property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                    body += property.Name + " = " + property.GetValue(obj, null) + Environment.NewLine;
                else
                {
                    if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        body = body + property.Name + ": {" + Environment.NewLine;
                        var list = (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(obj, null);
                        foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            body = body + item.GetType().Name + ": {" + DeconstructLists(item, "") + "}" + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                        body = body + "}" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
            }
            return body;
        }
    }
    public class Company
    {
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string regNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Asn> asns { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Contact
    {
        public int contactId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
    }
    public class Asn
    {
        public int asnId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public Company company { get; set; }
        public bool userBehalf { get; set; }
        public bool something { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I initially tried to do, but that also results in `list` being `null` despite the `property` it's being assigned to being `List<object>`.

Comment: The your problem is somewhere else. Better post a code before this snippet, in order to see what is `obj`, what is `property` etc.

Comment: Hmmm okay, it does display the correct property when stepping through but `var list` wouldn't be assigned to and always end up as `null`. I will post the model code and the other two methods.

Comment: Forget about the "alternative", it's incorrect. When you put a breakpoint in a debugger inside your `SendEmail`function, are you sure `cm.asns` and `cm.contacts` are not really `null`?

Comment: Yes, certain they're not null, they're saving to the database correctly. The alternative creates an infinite loop.

Comment: This is unbelievable! Are you saying that if you use just `object list = property.GetValue(obj, null);`, you get `null', but at the same moment looking at the debugger, `obj.propertyName` is not null?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89599/discussion-between-purplesmurph-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: Fixed! Added small edit to guarantee no null gets through. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this in your if statement ?

```
var genericType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
foreach (var prop in genericType.GetProperties())
{
    DeconstructLists(prop, body);
}
```

This topic may also help you: [How to get the type of T from a member of a generic class or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557340/how-to-get-the-type-of-t-from-a-generic-listt)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but still get errors `System.Type does not contain a public definition of GetEnumerator`

Comment: `List` != null! However now getting a `stackoverflow exception` on the first `if` statement.