# how to get values of generic object in generic object list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need help for get a object values, this object is in an object list, for example.

```
list<object> objectList = new list<object>();
objectList.Add( new {  id = 1,  name = "name1"});
objectList.Add( new {  id = 2,  name = "name2"});
```

the problem is I can't get the values of these objects inside the list, and put their values in a excel file, I tried this.

```
int row = 2
for(int i = 0; row < objectList ; i++){
 excelRow[row,1].Value = item[i].id
 excelRow[row,2].Value = item[i].name
row++
}
```

Comment: it's not a generic object it anonymouse object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an implicitly typed array to create an array that's actually typed to the anonymous type that you're using:

```
var objectList = new []
{
    new {  id = 1,  name = "name1"},
    new {  id = 2,  name = "name2"},
};
```

Once you've done that when you get an item from the collection it's actually it's real type (which has no name) rather than `object`.

Answer (score -1):

A dynamic object can fit for this