# why can't I create a list<T> of anonymous type in C#?

Tags: c#, list, .net-core, anonymous-types

I am new to `anonymous types` in c#, and I want to create a `list` of `anonymous types` that contain 3 variables: `string str`, `int num`, `DataTime time`.

however, when I try to use the code from this question`s answers:  [A generic list of anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)
it won't work for me.

I used a simple `Console application` to do it and I think I get the error
because I don't have `System.Core` because someone in the comment of the question above said that:

> (You also need a reference to System.Core of course.)

and I don't know what is `System.Core` and if I have it so it might be the problem

I do use `Systme.Linq`.

here is the code:

```cs
var list = new[] { str, num, time }.ToList();
list.add("hi", 5, DateTime.Now);

Console.WriteLine(list[0].num);
```

I also face issues when I try to specify the `type` of the `variables`
for example `string str`.

Comment: What error you are getting with this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya "time" does not exist in the correct context, same error for ```str``` and ```num```

Comment: You can not create a generic list for anonymous types. The question and answer you are referring to suggests how to create list containing anonymous type. That list is not generic list. About the error you are getting... `var list = new[] { str, num, time }.ToList(); code creates an array from three variables `str`, `num` and `time` and converts that array to list. Did you declare these variables in your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing some syntax. Anonymous types must be declared with `new{...}`. The property names must be declared *when they cannot be inferred by a variable name.* (You also have a typo in `Add`; it should be uppercase).

The below [works](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOyQExAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgBkBLTARwG4aydAaQDMDAN40G0pqVISpMmQDcICBrHUBeBgCJmdXQ37UlKtQ0zowDHQFYTZ6avUwOYOLYYARCPAAq7nAsAKowAMYAcgD2AO6OTi4MADYcsF6YcLEA2gC6EpZZEppIltalbh4AvlUs/tGcsAAUAJQJZqmwLACCODhNmbHiGjAIWroAFhy6pVZgWnYVQVq+AUEsMbEMVW2KZswAnE2dMNl0uSxzu6YyVTRVQA===):

```
var str = "string";
var num = 5;
var time = DateTime.UtcNow;
// notice double "new" 
// property names inferred to match variable names
var list = new[] { new { str, num, time } }.ToList(); 

// "new" again. Must specify property names since they cannot be inferred
list.Add(new { str = "hi", num = 5, time = DateTime.Now });

Console.WriteLine(list[0].num);
```

With that said, this is pretty clunky. I'd suggest writing a class with the properties you want, or using `ValueTuple`.

This [works](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxAgrgOyQExAagB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgBkBLTARwG4b6TcgBZ+tUnQGkAzAwDeNBkqalS8xcuUA3CAgaw9AXgYAiZnRMMxm7boaZ0YBsYCs1mwx16YHMHGcMACIQ8AAqvnAsAKowAMYAcgD2AO7uNl4MADYcsAGYcMkMnLAAPAAU5vowyAxcMPaOSEEhcOF+DD5+AJQAfGVdaZrZsCwAgjg4ZWUGTQ5gTZ1wXQMaNsMwYxNTJgAWHCZNLk3BYREsScnLg8rMAJxl6wDadAC6LHMr1JoAvjTfQA===) and is clearer/cleaner:

```
var list = new List<(string str, int num, DateTime time)>();

// ValueTuple are declared in parens, method calls require parens as well
// so we end up with two sets of parens, both required 
list.Add((str, num, time));
list.Add(("hi", 5, DateTime.Now));

Console.WriteLine(list[0].num);
```

Another reason to prefer your own class or `ValueTuple` is that you cannot declare a method as accepting an anonymous type. In otherwords, something *like* this is not valid:

```
public void DoSomethingWithAnonTypeList(List<???> theList ) { ... }
```

There is nothing* I can put to replace the `???` as anonymous types are both `internal` and have "unspeakable" names. You wouldn't be able to pass your list around and do something *meaningful* with it. So what's the point?

Conversely, I *can* declare a method as accepting a list of `ValueTuple`s:

```
public void DoSomethingWithTupleList(List<(string, int, DateTime)> theList) { 
     Console.WriteLine(theList[0].Item1);
}
```

or using named tuples:

```
public void DoSomethingWithTupleList(List<(string str, int num, DateTime time)> theList) { 
     Console.WriteLine(theList[0].time);
}
```

* You can technically pass your list of anonymous types to a generic method. However you won't be able to access the individual properties. The best you'd be able to do is access the list's `Count` or iterate over the list/enumerable and perhaps print the default `ToString` which doesn't really get you much either. There's not a generic constraint to help here. The third statement in this method will [generate a compiler error](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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):

```
public void DoSomethingGenerically<T>(List<T> theList) {

      Console.WriteLine(theList.Count); // valid
      Console.WriteLine(theList[0]); // valid, prints default ToString

      Console.WriteLine(theList[0].num); // invalid! What's the point?

}

var list = new[] { new { str = "hi", num = 5, time = DateTime.Now } }.ToList();
// valid due to type inference, but see comments above
DoSomethingGenerically(list);
```

Do note that you'll have the same issue with `ValueTuple`, I'm just clarifying my "do nothing" statement.

Comment: wow. this is the best answer I have ever seen in stack overflow.

Comment: Finally, I have peace